# Counterstrike 1.6 noforce command line parameters?

Tags: counter-strike

Does anybody know the noforce command line parameters for Counterstrike 1.6?

I have a monitor that runs with a refresh rate of 75hz and with the default configuration for graphics card setting when going online I get a lot of FPS lag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console commands to disable vsync in Counterstrike 1.6 is `gl_vsync 0`. Additionally, you might need the command `fps_max 100` to unlock your framerate (change "100" to whatever framerate you want Counterstrike to cap at).

The useful `noforce` command line parameters are:

`-noforcemparms -noforcemaccel` - disables mouse acceleration but has a little glide feel to it

`-noforcemparms -noforcemaccel -noforcemspd` - same as above but without the glide feeling to it

`-32bpp` - sets the game to use 32 bit colour depth by default

`-freq 100` - changes refresh rate to 100

`-nojoy` - disables joystick/gamepad

Comment: yeah gl_vsync 0 will do it. thnx plz give me the noforce command :)

Answer (score 0):

After an update, there is a new `noforce` command

```
-nomousegrab -nofbo -nomsaa -strechaspect -noforcemaccel -noforcemparms  -freq 75
```

Answer (score -1):

`-noforcemaccel` - Use desktop mouse acceleration settings

`-noforcemspd` - Use desktop mouse speed settings.

`-noforcemparms` - Use desktop mouse buttons settings.

See all the commands here http://www.nkscslovers.co.in/2014/04/how-to-set-launch-options-in-cs.html