# Counter Strike 1.6 Configurations

Tags: counter-strike, framerate

### Why are User configs so important?

I have seen lot of players on lan and general buzz on internet forums too as to what are the most optimal settings for counter strike 1.6.

---

What is the difference between server **"rates"** and client **"rates"** ? Why is it so important to ensure all my settings are right?
How does **FPS** affect the way my gun shoots?

Comment: Rates and framerate are not one and same.

Comment: Yes I know that, Those were individual questions. What do the sv_rate x,rate x cvar do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

optimal settings for ingame `counter-strike 1.6` vary from person to person,though certainly there are few things to remember that is logical.

first of all counter strike is a fps based game with little or no graphics.so better go with `800*600 resolution` than `1024*768`game is viewed closer with little bigger objects.
using `noforce command` is another trick where you are forcing few in-game settings by default.[see here for noforce](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147224/counterstrike-1-6-noforce-command-line-parameters)

disable mouse pointer precision from your pc`control panel` `mouse` settings.
disable all options from `mouse` in-game except `raw input` and `mouse look`
disable `translucent` from in-game
type in console `cl_dynamiccrosshair 0` to disable crosshair size fluctuation when firing.
disable unneccessary graphics option from your gfx(if you have) like vsync,tripple buferring,threaded optimization.
also type in console `gl_vsync 0`to disable vsync

server rates is the rate of response(packets) the server is able to sent you.client is the rate of acknowledge of recieved packets from server and sending forth. its not 100% synchronized.